# Accessing on premise MS Dynamics 3.0

Tags: dynamics-crm

I am working on MS Dynamics and using CRM SDK to access the entities of dynamics. Code is running fine when I enter the credentials of Dynamics CRM online. I am stuck in a case in which other organization has desktop version of Dynamics CRM ie. 3.0 and they have let me to access their CRM via VPN because they have installed Dynamics CRM on their local network. I want to access the data as I need to import the data in other database as per requirement. but code is not authenticating the credentials . May be something is going wrong when there creates a discovery URL or something else.

How can I resolve it ?

Comment: Only they can verify what's going on on their own network...

Comment: you are trying to connect to a CRM 3.0 instance with a recent CRM SDK (2011+)? good luck with that... it's impossible

Comment: What other approach I can opt to import data ( Except using excel)?